# Change text based on data attribute of input element with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to change paragraph text based on value of input attribute with jQuery.
If input `data-number` value is less than 50, change paragraph text to `50$`. I don't know how to target the `data-number` value.

```
<div>
  <p>5$</p>
  <input data-number="4.673001">
</div>
```

Comment: I'd suggest reading the jQuery documentation. http://api.jquery.com/data & http://api.jquery.com/text

Comment: Also note that `input` elements don't have a closing `</input>` tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must want to use `.each()` if you're going to have more than one `input` element.

Here is a working snippet:

```js
$('input[data-number]').each(function() {
  if ($(this).data('number') < 50) {
    $(this).siblings('p').html('50$');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p>5$</p>
  <input data-number="4.673001" />
</div>

<div>
  <p>52$</p>
  <input data-number="52" />
</div>

<div>
  <p>2$</p>
  <input data-number="2" />
</div>
```

Note that `input` doesn't need a closing tag as it's a self-closing element.

Some docs about the functions I used in this snippet:
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/
http://api.jquery.com/data/  (can be done with http://api.jquery.com/attr/ too)
https://api.jquery.com/siblings/

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. This snippet works on page load. And my data-number is dynamically generated. When data-number is changed, script no longer works. I wonder how this could be fixed.

Comment: I guess you could create a function like `function update_prices(){ /* put my code here */ }` and call it after your `data-number`s are (re)generated.

Answer (score 0):

You can target the data-number attribute using
`$('input).attr('data-number')`.